# Sum rows of data frame for each unique pair of values

Tags: r, sum, dataframe, aggregate

I have got a data frame that looks like this:

```
 > df
           date day        x    y   z
[1]  2014-02-24 Thursday   100  83  39
[2]  2014-02-26 Wednessday 486 189 171
[3]  2014-02-26 Wednessday 426 427 428
[4]  2014-02-26 Wednessday 423 286 195
[5]  2014-02-27 Thursday   374 339 229
[6]  2014-02-27 Thursday   744 496 489
```

I want to sum `x`, `y`, and `z` for each unique pair of `date` and `day` variables. It should look like this:

```
           date day        x    y   z
[1]  2014-02-24 Thursday   100  83  39
[2]  2014-02-26 Wednessday 1335 902 794
[6]  2014-02-27 Thursday   1118 835 718
```

Any help please?? thanks a lot!!

Comment: I believe you can use the `ave()` command, but what have you been able to try?

Comment: What you've shown looks more like the printout of a `matrix` than a `data.frame`. Have you looked at `aggregate`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto nope its a dataframe. I put the `[]` myself

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator `ave()` is not suitable because I want sums not averages...

Comment: I think I have used `ave()` with `FUN = sum` before, see this article link http://www.r-bloggers.com/ave-and-the-function-in-r/  please let me know if I am just way off base though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this (and many answers on SO) about how to do it.

Here are three common ways, one in base R, one using "data.table", and one using "dplyr".

```
aggregate(cbind(x, y, z) ~ date + day, mydf, sum)
#         date        day    x   y   z
# 1 2014-02-24   Thursday  100  83  39
# 2 2014-02-27   Thursday 1118 835 718
# 3 2014-02-26 Wednessday 1335 902 794

library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = list(date, day)]
#          date        day    x   y   z
# 1: 2014-02-24   Thursday  100  83  39
# 2: 2014-02-26 Wednessday 1335 902 794
# 3: 2014-02-27   Thursday 1118 835 718

library(dplyr)
mydf %>% group_by(date, day) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
# Groups: date
# 
#         date        day    x   y   z
# 1 2014-02-24   Thursday  100  83  39
# 2 2014-02-26 Wednessday 1335 902 794
# 3 2014-02-27   Thursday 1118 835 718
```

Answer (score -1):

Try tapply with artificial column that concatenates 'date' and 'day'.